# What is difference Between abstract and interface in java

Tags: java, methods, interface, abstract

Why the abstract method and interface should be used in java .Actually what is need explain with examples.How it's work.
When to use these methods and what is actual difference Between them.

I tried to implement interface but runtime error occurred

Comment: To fix the errors in your code we need to see the code and the error message. As far as abstract vs interface goes, this is covered in any introduction to java discussing these topics - please do a little research and post back with *practical* questions based on what you have learned. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources